# ASP.NET Core 3.0 Using DynamicRouteValueTransformer descendent spoils Identity

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, identity

I am trying to map an area to another one: say if area in the URL is "admin" I map it to "SomeArea". In effect I need to achieve kind of "area aliasing". This works well if area is plain MVC area, but results in a NullReferenceException when Identity pages are accessed (stack might be interesting!):

```
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages.Infrastructure.PageLoaderMatcherPolicy.ApplyAsync(HttpContext httpContext, CandidateSet candidates)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Matching.DfaMatcher.SelectEndpointWithPoliciesAsync(HttpContext httpContext, IEndpointSelectorPolicy[] policies, CandidateSet candidateSet)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointRoutingMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitMatch|8_1(EndpointRoutingMiddleware middleware, HttpContext httpContext, Task matchTask)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.MigrationsEndPointMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.EntityFrameworkCore.DatabaseErrorPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
 at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
```

The `DynamicRouteValueTransformer` is pretty simple - here's the `TransformAsync`method:

```
public override async ValueTask<RouteValueDictionary> TransformAsync(HttpContext httpContext, RouteValueDictionary values)
{
    if (values.ContainsKey("area") && ((string)values["area"]).Equals("admin", System.StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
    {
        values["area"] = "SomeArea";
    }

    return values;
}
```

In `Startup.cs` Transformer is registered like this (where exactly shouldn't be impoertant!):

> ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)

```
services.AddSingleton<SampleRouteTransformer>();
```

> Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)

```
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapDynamicControllerRoute<SampleRouteTransformer>("{area}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id:Guid?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "areas", pattern: "{area:exists}/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    endpoints.MapControllerRoute(name: "default", pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id:Guid?}");
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
});
```

Any ideas what's wrong? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: Apparently, I'm not the only one :( - https://www.gitmemory.com/issue/aspnet/AspNetCore/13116/521119375

**EDIT2**: After a closer look at the stack dump it becomes clear that something's wrong with EF Core migrations, most probably another one is needed. And indeed, after adding a migration it appeared that two tables in Identity schema have changed. Most probably this is a result of upgrading Identity to a new preview version. 
Here's the Up migration:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "Name",
    table: "AspNetUserTokens",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "LoginProvider",
    table: "AspNetUserTokens",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "ProviderKey",
    table: "AspNetUserLogins",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");

migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<string>(
    name: "LoginProvider",
    table: "AspNetUserLogins",
    maxLength: 128,
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(string),
    oldType: "nvarchar(450)");
```

Obviously, not a **clean, in depth explanation** of what exactly happens, but no exception now.

**@ASP.NET Core Team**: As a conclusion, maybe the exception thrown is a bit misleading. In other cases EF Core exceptions are caught and the messages are clear and helpful.